# Maven plugin AbstractMojoTestCase PlexusContainerException

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I'm trying to create a maven plugin for the first time.
everything works till now except for the testing part.
I want to write some test cases before I start at coding the plugin itself.
I've had really much trouble till now with being able to simply run a test case that doesn't even do anything itself.

I think I'm missing a dependency or that I'm using compatible versions. I've messed much with the versions and the exceptions have changed a lot. But this one keeps coming back.

So when I run `mvn test` I get the following response from the console:

```
λ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Web Share Plugin 1.2.9-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Using '' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory maven-sws-plugin\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to maven-sws-plugin\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Using '' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 1 mojo descriptors.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (mojo-descriptor) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Using '' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 1 mojo descriptors.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Using '' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sws-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: maven-sws-plugin\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running plugins.MojoTest
org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system:
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:624)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.construct(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:281)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:172)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.getContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:107)
        at nl.ciber.maven.plugins.MojoTest.setUp(MojoTest.java:11)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CycleDetectedInComponentGraphException: Cyclic requirement detected
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:65)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.DefaultComponentRepository.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRepository.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultComponentRegistry.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRegistry.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:514)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:969)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:941)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:560)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.CycleDetectedException: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:143)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:123)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:60)
        ... 35 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.726 sec <<< FAILURE!
testFilePath(***.maven.plugins.MojoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.686 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to create plexus container.
        at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.getContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:107)
        at ***.maven.plugins.MojoTest.setUp(MojoTest.java:11)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   testFilePath(***.maven.plugins.MojoTest): Failed to create plexus container.

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.595 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-24T10:35:35+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/497M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project sws-maven-plugin: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to maven-sws-plugin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My POM.xml (I've added a few things what are proberally not needed, I've googled a lot and nothing worked till now):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>***.maven.plugin.sws</groupId>
    <artifactId>sws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.2.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple Web Share Plugin</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.version>3.5.0-alpha-1</maven.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavencentral</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource.fabric</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric-maven-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.fuse-084</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>***.webshare</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-web-share-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-settings</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.5.5</version>-->
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My POM for testing:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>***.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>sws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.9.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>reminder-maven-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>***.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>sws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

TestCase:

```
package ***.maven.plugins;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;

/**
 * Created by casper.hollemans on 20-3-2017.
 */
public class MojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testFilePath() throws Exception {



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling a bit more, I've been able to fix the exceptions.
The main problem wat that my POM was growing a bit big full of unnecessary dependencies. I've looked into the git of the *maven clean plugin* and compared my pom with the pom of the clean plugin. The main issue was, as I expected; I used the wrong versions. I'll post my current pom over here and the link to the maven plugin's git.

- [Maven plugins github page](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins)
- [Maven clean plugin (project I used to compare to).](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/tree/trunk/maven-clean-plugin)

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>***.maven.plugin.sws</groupId>
    <artifactId>sws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.2.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple Web Share Plugin</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>****</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.version>3.0</maven.version>
    </properties>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>***.webshare</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-web-share-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependencies to annotations -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```